# GetInterfaceDnsSettings does not accept *mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I am trying to get the `ServerProperties` member from a `DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3` struct.

The documentation states to use `GetInterfaceDnsSettings`, and under the `Settings` parameter, it explicitly states that if the Version member is 3, the underlying struct should be `DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[GetInterfaceDnsSettings docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getinterfacednssettings)

I tried doing a manual type cast, there is no compile error, but the `cServerProperties` member is 0 for my WiFi network adapter even though I have configured DNS over HTTPS for it (Windows 11 machine).

```
// My GUID is valid and retrieved from GetAdaptersAddresses (and converting the LUID to GUID).

let mut dns_interface_settings: DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3 = Default::default();
dns_interface_settings.Version = DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS_VERSION3;

// This has an error: expected raw pointer `*mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS` found raw pointer `*mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3`

let dns_setting_result = GetInterfaceDnsSettings(guid, &mut dns_interface_settings as *mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS3);

// Or am I meant to do manual type cast?

let dns_setting_result = GetInterfaceDnsSettings(guid, &mut dns_interface_settings as *mut _ as *mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, the manual type cast works, and it was meant to return 0, because I configured DNS over HTTPS on a specific network, instead of my network adapter. After configuring it on my network adapter, it does return the correct setting.

`let dns_setting_result = GetInterfaceDnsSettings(guid, &mut dns_interface_settings as *mut _ as *mut DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS);`